# Android:add app widget to other apps

Tags: android, android-widget, homescreen, android-applicationinfo

I was going through app wigets tutorials from android official site.It says App widgets are

```
App Widgets are miniature application views that can be embedded in 
other  applications (such as the Home screen) and receive updates.
```

It defines it as views than can be embedded in other "applications" such as homescreen.It doesn't say just homescreen but applications such as homescreen.So i just want to know are there any other places where we can add app widget other than homescreen. Like adding other app widget to my application.

Comment: Any app can choose to use `AppWidgetHost` and related classes to support app widgets. Few apps outside of home screens do.

Comment: are there any realtime apps which shows this feature.

Comment: I have no idea what "realtime apps" are. While most likely there are non-home screen apps that host app widgets, I cannot name any off the top of my head.